# One to Many relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have implemented one to many relationship using hibernate. It is successfully stored in two tables by saving parent object.

<kbd>Table_1</kbd>

```
-------------------------
| ID_PK |  NAME  |  AGE |
-------------------------
|   100 | RAMESH |   24 | 
-------------------------
```

<kbd>Table_2</kbd>

```
----------------------------
| ID_PK | ID_FK |  ADDRESS | 
----------------------------
|     1 |   100 |      BTM |  
|     2 |   100 |     BTM1 |  
|     3 |   100 |     BTM2 |  
----------------------------
```

But I want to remove second value from Table_2 while updating first object.
Can you tell how to do?

Comment: Post the code that is saving your entities to the database.

Comment: I didn't write the code for this,Can you tell the way how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate you can use `SessionFactory` to save your entities in the database.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("Mark");
employee.setAge(24);
long id = (Long) session.save(employee);
session.flush(); //This will save your Employee entity to the mapped table.
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example) link to have a better understanding.

Comment: i am using one to many relationship and also i have done saving data now i want to remove one value from table_2 using saveOrUpdate().How to do?